# Automatically remove hot/dead pixels from an image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, camera, scipy

I am using numpy and scipy to process a number of images taken with a CCD camera. These images have a number of hot (and dead) pixels with very large (or small) values. These interfere with other image processing, so they need to be removed. Unfortunately, though a few of the pixels are stuck at either 0 or 255 and are always at the same value in all of the images, there are some pixels that are temporarily stuck at other values for a period of a few minutes (the data spans many hours).

I am wondering if there is a method for identifying (and removing) the hot pixels already implemented in python. If not, I am wondering what would be an efficient method for doing so. The hot/dead pixels are relatively easy to identify by comparing them with neighboring pixels. I could see writing a loop that looks at each pixel, compares its value to that of its 8 nearest neighbors. Or, it seems nicer to use some kind of convolution to produce a smoother image and then subtract this from the image containing the hot pixels, making them easier to identify.

I have tried this "blurring method" in the code below, and it works okay, but I doubt that it is the fastest. Also, it gets confused at the edge of the image (probably since the gaussian_filter function is taking a convolution and the convolution gets weird near the edge). So, is there a better way to go about this?

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)

#make a sample image
x = np.linspace(-5,5,200)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = 255*np.cos(np.sqrt(x**2 + Y**2))**2


for i in range(0,11):
    #Add some hot pixels
    Z[np.random.randint(low=0,high=199),np.random.randint(low=0,high=199)]= np.random.randint(low=200,high=255)
    #and dead pixels
    Z[np.random.randint(low=0,high=199),np.random.randint(low=0,high=199)]= np.random.randint(low=0,high=10)

#Then plot it
ax1.set_title('Raw data with hot pixels')
ax1.imshow(Z,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower')

#Now we try to find the hot pixels
blurred_Z = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(Z, sigma=2)
difference = Z - blurred_Z

ax2.set_title('Difference with hot pixels identified')
ax2.imshow(difference,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower')

threshold = 15
hot_pixels = np.nonzero((difference>threshold) | (difference<-threshold))

#Don't include the hot pixels that we found near the edge:
count = 0
for y,x in zip(hot_pixels[0],hot_pixels[1]):
    if (x != 0) and (x != 199) and (y != 0) and (y != 199):
        ax2.plot(x,y,'ro')
        count += 1

print 'Detected %i hot/dead pixels out of 20.'%count
ax2.set_xlim(0,200); ax2.set_ylim(0,200)


plt.show()
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: Try a more  simple case: make another image with median filtering (for example, by a pattern 3x3) and compute absolute value of differense between your image and filtered image. Substitute pixels of original image with big values of that difference (lets say, 100) by filtered values. Value of threshold you can get automatically by statistics of difference.

Comment: @Eddy_Em, thanks for suggesting the median filter - this does seem like a better method than the gaussian filter. Also, I like the idea of setting the threshold using the statistics of the difference array. I tried taking the standard deviation and this seemed to work well. (I set the threshold at 5 times the standard deviation.) However, I am confused about your suggestion to add a multiple of the difference array to the image array. What does this do?

Comment: Oh, no: I just mean that you search pixels to clean up in the difference array by some thresholding value.

Comment: Okay, that's what I'm now doing. This seems to work pretty well with the median filter. There is still an edge effect where the median filter produces a different result near the edge and so it makes it seems like there are lots of hot pixels there. Any idea how to make it work near the edge? Currently, I am just ignoring the edge, but this seems like an inelegant solution.

Comment: You can try simple adaptive median filtering which kernel changes: it is square 3x3 in centre of image, quasi-triangular on the edge and triangular on angles.

Comment: @Eddy_Em, I like this idea, but I am struggling with finding a good way to create the adaptive kernel... Doesn't median_filter just take a single kernel?

Comment: Nice question! There are tonnes of astronomy strategies available e.g. https://github.com/astropy/astroscrappy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, I think that the fastest way to deal with hot pixels is just to use a size=2 median filter. Then, poof, your hot pixels are gone and you also kill all sorts of other high-frequency sensor noise from your camera.

If you really want to remove ONLY the hot pixels, then substituting you can subtract the median filter from the original image, as I did in the question, and replace only these values with the values from the median filtered image. This doesn't work well at the edges, so if you can ignore the pixels along the edge, then this will make things a lot easier.

If you want to deal with the edges, you can use the code below. However, it is not the fastest:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)

#make some sample data
x = np.linspace(-5,5,200)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = 100*np.cos(np.sqrt(x**2 + Y**2))**2 + 50

np.random.seed(1)
for i in range(0,11):
    #Add some hot pixels
    Z[np.random.randint(low=0,high=199),np.random.randint(low=0,high=199)]= np.random.randint(low=200,high=255)
    #and dead pixels
    Z[np.random.randint(low=0,high=199),np.random.randint(low=0,high=199)]= np.random.randint(low=0,high=10)

#And some hot pixels in the corners and edges
Z[0,0]   =255
Z[-1,-1] =255
Z[-1,0]  =255
Z[0,-1]  =255
Z[0,100] =255
Z[-1,100]=255
Z[100,0] =255
Z[100,-1]=255

#Then plot it
ax1.set_title('Raw data with hot pixels')
ax1.imshow(Z,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower')

def find_outlier_pixels(data,tolerance=3,worry_about_edges=True):
    #This function finds the hot or dead pixels in a 2D dataset. 
    #tolerance is the number of standard deviations used to cutoff the hot pixels
    #If you want to ignore the edges and greatly speed up the code, then set
    #worry_about_edges to False.
    #
    #The function returns a list of hot pixels and also an image with with hot pixels removed

    from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
    blurred = median_filter(Z, size=2)
    difference = data - blurred
    threshold = tolerance*np.std(difference)

    #find the hot pixels, but ignore the edges
    hot_pixels = np.nonzero((np.abs(difference[1:-1,1:-1])>threshold) )
    hot_pixels = np.array(hot_pixels) + 1 #because we ignored the first row and first column

    fixed_image = np.copy(data) #This is the image with the hot pixels removed
    for y,x in zip(hot_pixels[0],hot_pixels[1]):
        fixed_image[y,x]=blurred[y,x]
        
    if worry_about_edges == True:
        height,width = np.shape(data)
    
        ###Now get the pixels on the edges (but not the corners)###

        #left and right sides
        for index in range(1,height-1):
            #left side:
            med  = np.median(data[index-1:index+2,0:2])
            diff = np.abs(data[index,0] - med)
            if diff>threshold: 
                hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[index],[0]]  ))
                fixed_image[index,0] = med
            
            #right side:
            med  = np.median(data[index-1:index+2,-2:])
            diff = np.abs(data[index,-1] - med)
            if diff>threshold: 
                hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[index],[width-1]]  ))
                fixed_image[index,-1] = med

        #Then the top and bottom
        for index in range(1,width-1):
            #bottom:
            med  = np.median(data[0:2,index-1:index+2])
            diff = np.abs(data[0,index] - med)
            if diff>threshold: 
                hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[0],[index]]  ))
                fixed_image[0,index] = med
            
            #top:
            med  = np.median(data[-2:,index-1:index+2])
            diff = np.abs(data[-1,index] - med)
            if diff>threshold: 
                hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[height-1],[index]]  ))
                fixed_image[-1,index] = med
                  
        ###Then the corners###

        #bottom left
        med  = np.median(data[0:2,0:2])
        diff = np.abs(data[0,0] - med)
        if diff>threshold: 
            hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[0],[0]]  ))
            fixed_image[0,0] = med
        
        #bottom right
        med  = np.median(data[0:2,-2:])
        diff = np.abs(data[0,-1] - med)
        if diff>threshold: 
            hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[0],[width-1]]  ))
            fixed_image[0,-1] = med

        #top left
        med  = np.median(data[-2:,0:2])
        diff = np.abs(data[-1,0] - med)
        if diff>threshold: 
            hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[height-1],[0]]  ))
            fixed_image[-1,0] = med

        #top right
        med  = np.median(data[-2:,-2:])
        diff = np.abs(data[-1,-1] - med)
        if diff>threshold: 
            hot_pixels = np.hstack(( hot_pixels, [[height-1],[width-1]]  ))
            fixed_image[-1,-1] = med
    
    return hot_pixels,fixed_image


hot_pixels,fixed_image = find_outlier_pixels(Z)

for y,x in zip(hot_pixels[0],hot_pixels[1]):
    ax1.plot(x,y,'ro',mfc='none',mec='r',ms=10)

ax1.set_xlim(0,200)
ax1.set_ylim(0,200)

ax2.set_title('Image with hot pixels removed')
ax2.imshow(fixed_image,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',clim=(0,255))

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Can you use edge-mirroring here,  to avoid the complex handling of the edges and corners? I.e.:  `blurred = median_filter(image_data, size=2, mode="mirror")`

Comment: You are not using `tolerance=3` parameter in your code at all. It even seems that you are not using its default value when  setting `threshold = 10*np.std(difference)`.

Comment: Good catch. Changing the line to `threshold = tolerance * np.std(difference)` fixes the issue, correct? (I made the change to the above code.)